# Display first comment of post outside the comments template (using SQL maybe)

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

in Wordpress, how can I find and display the first comment or the comment of an administrator outside of the comments table?

I imagine like an sql query that displays the first comment of the post...

Any clues?
Thank you!

This is a function that gets 5 recent comments of all posts. I would like to edit this and show the latest of the post I am reading

```
function showLatestComments() {
  global $wpdb;  
  $sql = "
   SELECT DISTINCT comment_post_ID, comment_author, comment_date_gmt, comment_approved, SUBSTRING(comment_content,1,100) AS com_excerpt 
   FROM $wpdb->comments 
   WHERE comment_approved = '1'
   ORDER BY comment_date_gmt DESC 
   LIMIT 5";  
 $comments = $wpdb->get_results($sql);  
 $output .= '<h2>latest comments</h2><ul id="comm">';  
 foreach ($comments as $comment) { 
   $output .= '<li><strong>'. $comment->comment_author . ' said</strong> : "' . strip_tags($comment->com_excerpt). '..."</li>';
   }
 $output .= '</ul>';  
 echo $output;  
}//end function
```

Comment: In a question such as this, [code is king](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints). In other words, show us [sample code](http://sscce.org/) (describe tables and data in SQL) and desired output. Format lines as code by indenting them four extra spaces; he "{}" button in the editor toolbar does this for you. Wrap output in `<blockquote><pre>` elements. Click the orange question mark in the editor toolbar for more information and tips on formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the database structure of WordPress, but basicly you would have to get the ID of the current post and pass that along as a WHERE parameter.

I assume comment_post_ID keeps track of the ID of the post the comment was added to? Ifso:

```
$id = mysql_escape_string($_GET["id"]); // get id of post somewhere
  $sql = "
   SELECT DISTINCT comment_post_ID, comment_author, comment_date_gmt, comment_approved, SUBSTRING(comment_content,1,100) AS com_excerpt 
   FROM $wpdb->comments 
   WHERE comment_approved = '1' AND comment_post_ID = {$id}
   ORDER BY comment_date_gmt DESC 
   LIMIT 5";
```

That would show the 5 most recent comments to the post of which you pass along the id

Comment: Thank you! I am checking it now!

Comment: Works great! ( i edited the get post id function to work with wordpress) Thank you!

Comment: I have another question! How can I check if the commenter has a specific user_role (admin, editor...) or a user_level if it is easier?

I found that e.g. administrator is in this query 
`SELECT *
FROM `mydatabase`.`wp_usermeta`
WHERE (
`umeta_id` LIKE '%administrator%'
OR `user_id` LIKE '%administrator%'
OR `meta_key` LIKE '%administrator%'
OR `meta_value` LIKE '%administrator%'
)
LIMIT 0 , 30`

Comment: I have no idea how user roles are getting stored in the wordpress database, sorry. You'll have to give more information about how the user roles data is getting stored in the database

Answer (score 0):

I take it that "first post" means the earliest comment.  One simple way is to change the order (so earlier comments come first), then take the first row.

```
$sql = "
 SELECT DISTINCT comment_post_ID, comment_author, comment_date_gmt, 
     comment_approved, SUBSTRING(comment_content,1,100) AS com_excerpt 
 FROM $wpdb->comments 
 WHERE comment_approved = '1'
 ORDER BY comment_date_gmt ASC 
 LIMIT 1";
```

Only these two lines need to be changed if you do it this way.

```
 ORDER BY comment_date_gmt ASC 
 LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your interest and answer. I would like to put that code into single.php and display me the first comment of the current post

Comment: Since you accepted an answer that returns the last five comments instead of the first one comment, I'd say you probably don't really need to do that. ;-)